# I've closed debugging screens but I don't know how to re-open them

Tags: visual-studio-2008

Once I've, while working with VS, I saw several screens popping up in a disorganized fashion. Since I didn't try know what were them, I just close them all. Now, it looks like I closed what I closed were debugging screens. In fact, when I start an application in debugging mode (f5), I don't see any of them.

I'd like to how I can get them back (where to look for). I want especially the screen that allows me to check the value of local variables.

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you were asking specifically for the window that shows information about local variables as you step forward - I'm pretty sure that this is the Locals window that @leppie pointed out in the Debug>Windows menu.

For reference, there are 3 main windows that you can use to investigate variables as you step through code:

- Locals: This shows you information about the variables currently in context as you step through code
- Watch: This allows you to set up references to data that you want to watch as you are debugging
- Autos: This is similar to Locals, except it only shows variables that are used in the current and previous statement

HTH

Comment: @Mike Goalty -- I've re-open the 3  screens (Locals, Watch, and Autos) as you suggested. But, when I click f5, all those screens remain blank. Is there some more steps I need to take?

Comment: Nope, no more steps as far as I know. Are you using VB.NET or C#? If you're using C# then F5 will run the application and the windows won't be updated - try putting a breakpoint in a method that has local variables or parameters and see if anything appears in the Locals window.

Comment: Goalthy -- Thanks. I'm using C#. Once I've put a break point somewhere, all the local variables were visible. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Menu bar - Debug -> Windows -> The ones you need.

Comment: @leppie, @Oded -- I've just seen screens that are proposed (Break Points, Output, Auto, Locals). None of them is the screen I'm looking for. The screen I'm talking about allow me to check value of all the variables each time I move a step forward.

Comment: @Richard77 - that's the immediate window.

Comment: The immediate screen is blank when I press f5. Is there anything else to do to make it display my variables?

Comment: Once you have stopped in a breakpoint, it should allow you to query local variables. On second thought, you may mean the Locals window - it will show all Local variables.

Comment: @Richard77 - Put a break point in the place you need to inspect. How else is VS supposed to know which method you want to look at?

Answer (score 1):

Under Debug menu, Windows submenu. More items will appear during debug mode.